# Using c# to read from a text file

Tags: c#

Am reading from a text file using the code below.

```
if (!allLines.Contains(":70"))
{
     var firstIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":20");
     var secondIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":23B");
     var thirdIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":59");
     var fourthIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":71A");
     var fifthIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":72");
     var sixthIndex = allLines.IndexOf("-}");
     var firstValue = allLines.Substring(firstIndex + 4, secondIndex - firstIndex - 5).TrimEnd();
     var secondValue = allLines.Substring(thirdIndex + 4, fourthIndex - thirdIndex - 5).TrimEnd();
     var thirdValue = allLines.Substring(fifthIndex + 4, sixthIndex - fifthIndex - 5).TrimEnd();
     var len1 = firstValue.Length;
     var len2 = secondValue.Length;
     var len3 = thirdValue.Length;
     inflow103.REFERENCE = firstValue.TrimEnd();
     pointer = 1;
     inflow103.BENEFICIARY_CUSTOMER = secondValue;
     inflow103.RECEIVER_INFORMATION = thirdValue;
}
else if (allLines.Contains(":70"))
{
     var firstIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":20");
     var secondIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":23B");
     var thirdIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":59");
     var fourthIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":70");
     var fifthIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":71");
     var sixthIndex = allLines.IndexOf(":72");
     var seventhIndex = allLines.IndexOf("-}");
     var firstValue = allLines.Substring(firstIndex + 4, secondIndex - firstIndex - 5).TrimEnd();
     var secondValue = allLines.Substring(thirdIndex + 5, fourthIndex - thirdIndex - 5).TrimEnd();
     var thirdValue = allLines.Substring(sixthIndex + 4, seventhIndex - sixthIndex - 5).TrimEnd();
     var len1 = firstValue.Length;
     var len2 = secondValue.Length;
     var len3 = thirdValue.Length;
     inflow103.REFERENCE = firstValue.TrimEnd();
     pointer = 1;
     inflow103.BENEFICIARY_CUSTOMER = secondValue;
     inflow103.RECEIVER_INFORMATION = thirdValue;
}
```

Below is the format of the text file am reading.

```
{1:F21DBLNNGLAAXXX4695300820}{4:{177:1405260906}{451:0}}{1:F01DBLNNGLAAXXX4695300820}{2:O1030859140526SBICNGLXAXXX74790400761405260900N}{3:{103:NGR}{108:AB8144573}{115:3323774}}{4:
:20:SBICNG958839-2
:23B:CRED
:23E:SDVA
:32A:140526NGN168000000,
:50K:IHS PLC
:53A:/3000025296
SBICNGLXXXX
:57A:/3000024426
DBLNNGLA
:59:/0040186345
SONORA CAPITAL AND INVSTMENT LTD
:71A:OUR
:72:/CODTYPTR/001
-}{5:{MAC:00000000}{PAC:00000000}{CHK:42D0D867739F}}{S:{SPD:}{SAC:}{FAC:}{COP:P}}
```

The above file format represent one transaction in a single text file, but while testing with live files, I came accross a situation where a file can have more than one transaction. Example is the code below.

```
{1:F21DBLNNGLAAXXX4694300150}{4:{177:1405231923}{451:0}}{1:F01DBLNNGLAAXXX4694300150}{2:O1031656140523FCMBNGLAAXXX17087957771405231916N}{3:{103:NGR}{115:3322817}}{4:
:20:TRONGN3RDB16
:23B:CRED
:23E:SDVA
:26T:001
:32A:140523NGN1634150,00
:50K:/2206117013
SUNLEK INVESTMENT LTD
:53A:/3000024763
FCMBNGLA
:57A:/3000024426
DBLNNGLA
:59:/0022617678
GOLDEN DC INT'L LTD
:71A:OUR
:72:/CODTYPTR/001
//BNF/TRSF
-}{5:{MAC:00000000}{PAC:00000000}{CHK:C21000C4ECBA}{DLM:}}{S:{SPD:}{SAC:}{FAC:}{COP:P}}${1:F21DBLNNGLAAXXX4694300151}{4:{177:1405231923}{451:0}}{1:F01DBLNNGLAAXXX4694300151}{2:O1031656140523FCMBNGLAAXXX17087957781405231916N}{3:{103:NGR}{115:3322818}}{4:
:20:TRONGN3RDB17
:23B:CRED
:23E:SDVA
:26T:001
:32A:140523NGN450000,00
:50K:/2206117013
SUNLEK INVESTMENT LTD
:53A:/3000024763
FCMBNGLA
:57A:/3000024426
DBLNNGLA
:59:/0032501697
SUNSTEEL INDUSTRIES LTD
:71A:OUR
:72:/CODTYPTR/001
//BNF/TRSF
-}{5:{MAC:00000000}{PAC:00000000}{CHK:01C3B7B3CA53}{DLM:}}{S:{SPD:}{SAC:}{FAC:}{COP:P}}
```

My challenge is that in my code, while reading allLines, each line is identified by certain index, a situation where I need to pick up the second transaction from the file, and the same index exist like as before, how can I manage this situation.

Comment: Your messages seem to be separated by a dollar sign (`$`).

Comment: Off-topic but you could easily move indexes 1,2,3,6, and 7 outside of the if statement (along with other variables such as first and third value..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple problem obscured by excess code. All you are doing is extracting 3 values from a chunk of text where the precise layout can vary from one chunk to another.

There are 3 things I think you need to do.

1. Refactor the code. Instead of two hefty if blocks inline, you need functions that extract the required text.
2. Use regular expressions. A single regular expression can extract the values you need in one line instead of several.
3. Separate the code from the data. The logic of these two blocks is identical, only the data changes. So write one function and pass in the regular expression(s) needed to extract the data items you need.

Unfortunately this calls for a significant lift in the abstraction level of the code, which may be beyond what you're ready for. However, if you can do this and (say) you have function Extract() with regular expressions as arguments, you can apply that function once, twice or as often as needed to handle variations in your basic transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You may perhaps use the code below to achieve multiple record manipulation using your existing code

```
    //assuming fileText is all the text read from the text file
    string[] fileData = fileText.Split('$');
    foreach(string allLines in fileData)
    {
        //your code goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe indexing works, but given the particular structure of the format, I highly doubt that is a good solution. But if it works for you, then that's great. You can simply split on `$` and then pass each substring into a method. This assures that the index for each substring starts at the beginning of the entry.

However, if you run into a situation where indices are no longer static, then before you even start to write a parser for any format, you need to first understand the format. If you don't have any documentation and are basically reverse engineering it, that's what you need to do. Maybe someone else has specifications. Maybe the source of this data has it somewhere. But I will proceed under the assumption that none of this information is available and you have been given a task with absolutely no support and are expected to reverse-engineer it.

Any format that is meant to be parsed and written by a computer will 9 out of 10 times be well-formed. I'd say 9.9 out of 10 for that matter, since there are cases where people make things unnecessarily complex for the sake of "security".

When I look at your sample data, I see "chunks" of data enclosed within curly braces, as well as nested chunks.

For example, you have things like

```
{tag1:value1} // simple chunk
{tag2:{tag3: value3}{tag4:value4}} // nested chunk
```

Multiple transactions are delimited by a `$` apparently. You may be able to split on `$` signs in this case, but again you need to be sure that the `$` is a special character and doesn't appear in tags or values themselves.

Do not be fixated on what a "chunk" is or why I use the term. All you need to know is that there are "tags" and each tag comes with a particular "value".

The value can be anything: a primitive such as a string or number, or it can be another chunk. This suggests that you need to first figure out what type of value each tag accepts. For example, the `1` tag takes a string. The `4` tag takes multiple chunk, possibly representing different companies. There are chunks like `DLM` that have an empty value.

From these two samples, I would assume that you need to consume each each chunk, check the tag, and then parse the value. Since there are nested chunks, you likely need to store them in a particular way to correctly handle it.